# Backup Issues: in love with blog posts

Tags: backup, wget, curl, local

I fell in love with good blog posts only recently. Nevertheless, I have already piled up a bunch of urls to the good ones.

**I begin to worry that ten years later, many of them will no longer be hosted.** Luckily, unlike other kinds of modern fancy webpages, what I value the most in blog posts are the text, links, and images, which should be much easier to back up.

I wish there's a way that backs up the specified html, and all the resources linked at that page (with depth 1), so I can read the webpage without a problem on my local machine whenever I want until my death. Also, I wish that the backup files will integrate to each other coherently: say I want to back up `site-1:page-1` and `site-1:page-2`, the program will be smart enough to merge them together.

I am aware of and had tried `curl` and `wget`. I don't fully understand all the possible options, and maybe that's why I always find the resulting back-up files are a bit messy.

#### Question:

Is there a known way that fulfills what I wish? A simple, self-integrating, depth-1 backing up method that also creates an index?

Thank you very much in advance. Please let me know if I should be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to save website pages:

- In the browser do *Save As* a complete HTML page
- Print to a PDF printer and save the file
- Keep also a URL to those pages on the
  [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/)

If saved on the computer, any text-search program will serve.